# CakePHP 2.1 - AuthComponent::user() only gives me ID, Email, Password (hashed)

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.1

I'm trying to use `AuthComponent::user('first_name')` to access the users firstname and show it in a view. If I do `debug(AuthComponent::user());` I see that I can only access the ID, Email and password of the currently logged in user but not his name etc.

Do I have to specify which userdata is available when the user is logged in or should this happen automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The session is filled on the $this->Auth->login() call.
Everything you commit to this Method is stored in the session.

Also see the API:
http://api20.cakephp.org/class/auth-component#method-AuthComponentlogin

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Might be helpful to others if this would be referenced here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user